# Access 2007 Query Def Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

this is really frustrating and I'm hoping you can help me.  I keep getting a syntax error no matter what I do on this query.  I've read about putting parantheses on multiple joins but I did that and it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for your time.

```
Set PTI = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qry_PTImport", "SELECT DISTINCT" & _
            " bl.LoanNumber" & _
            ", qcq.Code" & _
            ", t.ecType" & _
            ", eb.QueryNo" & _
            ", q.QueryName" & _
            ", q.Description" & _
            ", q.suggestedAction" & _
            ", bd.datetransfer" & _
            ", bd.datebrd " & _
            "FROM ((((dbo.eCs_QCqueue qcq " & _
            "JOIN dbo.eCs_Queries q ON q.QueryNo = eb.QueryNo) " & _
            "JOIN brd_loan bl ON bl.serialID = qcq.serialID) " & _
            "JOIN dbo.eCs_Type t ON t.ectypeid = q.ectypeid) " & _
            "JOIN brd_deal bd ON bd.Code = bl.Code) " & _
            "WHERE qcq.Code = '" & Deal & "'")
```

Comment: it says Syntax error in JOIN operation.

Comment: Where is the table alias `eb` defined?

Comment: Access SQL does not accept just `JOIN`.  You have to tell it which type of join you want, so must include `INNER`, `LEFT`, or `RIGHT`.

Comment: Did you make this in the designer then copy/paste to VBA? Because the parentheses need to be just right with that many joins.

Comment: Does your Access database really include tables whose names contain periods: dbo.eCs_QCqueue; dbo.eCs_Queries; and dbo.eCs_Type? If those are really their names, you will probably need to bracket them ... [dbo.eCs_QCqueue] and so forth.

Comment: I'm going through some other errors here that I might need to clear up before this, but I think the numerous things mentioned here are all contributing to this not working.  I'll revisit this ASAP.  @HansUp, just so you know, this is eventually going to be a passthrough and the dbo. is part of that, not tables with periods in names.

Comment: Access and SQL Server's SQL dialects are different enough that you should make that point clear **in the question** so you spare other helpers the frustration of offering suggestions only to later discover they don't apply.

Comment: @HansUp you're absolutely right, sorry about that.  Will be more detailed from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wanted to say user HansUp was right in this instance of what my problem was.  VBA doesn't do just `JOIN`s.